# Inline cache <script> of ajax content

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, caching

I need to cache some `<script src>` that I receive via AJAX. Currently each call try to load the `src` via AJAX, as default. But the problem is that this script never change in a session and I need only *re-eval* this on document.

To be more clear, take this example of AJAX content result:

```
<strong>Hello World!</strong>
<script src="hello-world.js"></script>
```

If I call this AJAX three times, the `hello-world.js` is called three times too, but I need only re-execute this, without try to download it again. Browser cache help a lot, but I really do not can download it again every time.

I like to set some `data` to `script`, to jQuery know that I want only re-execute it, instead of download again. Like:

```
<script src="hello-world.js" data-cache="true"></script>
```

Any solution?

Comment: Shouldn't the browser handle this for you with normal caching, assuming your server is returning the appropriate headers for cacheable content?

Comment: Basically yes, but I have many things to consider: if I put all scripts inline, will generate a lot data from each call; if I use the browser cache it'll ask the server for each script file, a lot of individual scripts will be a big problem with high latency (what was my case), and last, script will never change in a session. Thanks for reply!

Comment: Then use, using data-src would be a good way of solving it. It also solves the weirdnes of including inline scripts when using .load (they don't seem to always run in the order you'd expect them to).

Answer (score 0):

If think about a good solution for my case... I just replaced the `src` with `data-src`, so jQuery will not get the content automatically, so I have time to work with my content and find `data-src` and create my own cache system. Works fine to me.

You can check my code here:

```
// Cache system (outside of AJAX engine)
var script_cache = {};

// Inside of [jQuery.ajax].success method
// where "data_html" is my jQuery(data_html) AJAX response.

// Find all script with data-src
jQuery('script[data-src]', data_html).each(function() {
    var self = jQuery(this),
        self_src = self.data('src');

    // If data was loaded before, so just execute it again
    if(typeof script_cache[self_src] !== "undefined") {
        jQuery.globalEval(script_cache[self_src]);
    }
    // Else, will load, cache and execute now
    // Note that we download with dataType text
    else {
        jQuery.ajax(self_src, {
            dataType: "text"
        }).success(function(data) {
            script_cache[self_src] = data;
            jQuery.globalEval(data);
        });
    }

    // Finally we remove the node, only to avoid problem
    self.remove();
});
```

Alternative solutions are welcome.